# Binding To Element Text In AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to bind to the text of an element without actually dropping into the link function?

```
<blink>Text Here or {{ controllerText() }}</blink>

// add a namespace for custom directives
angular.module('mydirectives', []);

angular.module('mydirectives').directive('blink', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<marquee scrollamount="100%">{{ can i do it here? }} </marquee>',
      scope: {
         // can i do it here?
      }
   };
});
```

Comment: Do you mean transclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is done with transclusion which merges the content of the original element with the template.  The ng-transclude tag in the template is required to get it to work.

```
<blink>Bring the blink back<blink>

// add a namespace for custom directives
angular.module('mydirectives', []);

angular.module('mydirectives').directive('blink', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      template: '<marquee scrollamount="100%" ng-transclude></marquee>'
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You absolute can.

```
scope: {
    text: '='
}
```

This adds a `text` attribute to the isolate scope that is linked to the value of the `text` attribute from the element.

So you need to change the html slightly to:

```
<blink text="fromController"></blink>
```

And then add that `fromController` attribute in the enclosing controller.

[Here's a (very annoying) fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87RhB/).

Comment: This is a perfect solution if you wanted to pass the text in as an attribute rather than as the contents of the tag.

Comment: I like this too. Not what I was after, but it wasn't long before I needed to do this too.  Many thanks!